# how to pass the values from drop down to URL in django

Tags: html, django

I am trying to prepare a simple UI. In which user will select the `roboid` from a dropdown on clicking the submit button he should get the robot details using a rest API URL. If I hardcode the `roboid` I am getting the results. But my doubt here is how to pass the value from drop down to URL. And how to display that json in tabular form in same window.

Here is my code:

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
import ast
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests
from .form import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    title = 'welcome'
    k = {}
    form = NameForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form, "title": title, "roboid": 2}
    if form.is_valid():

        robotid = request.POST.get('roboid', '')
        print robotid

        resp = requests.get('https://r0p1i0hwdh.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/testhp/?roboid=%s' % robotid)
        l = ast.literal_eval(resp.content)
        di = ast.literal_eval("".join(map(str, l)))
        for k, v in di.iteritems():
            items = "{:<25} {:<50}".format(k, v)
        context = {
            "robotid": robotid}

    return render(request, "name.html", context)
```

name.html
class a:

```
< !DOCTYPE html >
< html

< head >

< / head >
< body bgcolor = "#f5f5dc" >
< center >
<h1 > {{title}} < / h1 >

< form
method = "get"
action = "" >
{ % csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}

< script >
var
z = "https://bvdruneuqc.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/my-resource1?roboid=5"
< / script >
< input
type = "submit"
value = "Submit"
style = "float: none "
onclick = "window.open(z)" / >
< input
type = "RESET"
value = "cancel" >
{{items}}

< / form >< / center >
< / body >< / html >
```

form.py

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
roboid = forms.ChoiceField(label='RobotID',choices=[(x, x) for x in          range(1, 10)],required='TRUE',)
```

I know there are lot more to modify in the code.
But please help me guys, Its a kind of important for me.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your template, that's unreadable.

Comment: And, argh. Why are you using `literal_eval`` to parse JSON?

Comment: sorry for that also.... I dont know how t add the code again.This is the first time i posted the question

Comment: about that literal eval i dont want the data to be displayed in json form,actually i want to display it in table form but i dont know how to do that so for now i added that

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question is not clear properly. So, I am replying what I understand from your query.

Change your form method from **get** to **post** in **name.html** so that it can send request to your view and form can be validated using request.POST.

And jquery is addded to get the selected roboid and append in url.
You can also append the selected roboid in your API also which is comment below. You can use according to your need.

**name.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#f5f5dc">
    <center>
        <h1> {{title}} </h1>
        <form method="post" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <script>
                var z = "https://bvdruneuqc.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/my-resource1";

                $(document).on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var roboid = $("#id_roboid option:selected").val();
                    $('form').attr('action', "?roboid=" + roboid).submit();

                    // var new_z = z + "?roboid=" + roboid;
                    // window.open(new_z);
                });
            </script>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="float:none" />
            <input type="RESET" value="cancel"> {{items}}
        </form>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

In view.py since roboid is send by appending in the URL so it can be fetch from the request.GET

**views.py**

```
def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    title = 'welcome'
    k = {}
    form = NameForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form, "title": title, "roboid": 2}
    if form.is_valid():

        robotid = request.GET.get('roboid', '')
        print ('robotid', robotid)

        resp = requests.get('https://r0p1i0hwdh.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/testhp/?roboid=%s' % robotid)
        l = ast.literal_eval(resp.content)
        di = ast.literal_eval("".join(map(str, l)))
        for k, v in di.iteritems():
            items = "{:<25} {:<50}".format(k, v)
        context = {
            "robotid": robotid}

    return render(request, "name.html", context)
```

**And how to display that json in tabular form in same window.**
For that can you provide the data i.e a short example of json format you want to show in window and variable you are using. becasue for now **items** valriable is not added anywhere in the context so it cannot be access in the name.html

Comment: Hi Ashish, Thanks for the help.Here I am providing my sample json data:[
            {
                "Book ID": "1",
                "Book Name": "Computer Architecture",
                "Category": "Computers",
                "Price": "125.60"
            }]

Comment: Hi Ashish Can you please tell me how to pass more than one value to URL. (multiple id's)